# ViewModel with generic data into datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, generics, mvvm, datagrid

I have a parameter model class with generic value. I want to change the style of the datagridcell according to the value's type. I have a list of parameter with different type. But i don't know how to bind the Collection with the datagrid.

Here is my code so far.

```
public class ParameterModel<T> : IParameterModel
{
    public T Value { get; set; }
    public T DefaultValue { get; set; }
    public T MaxValue { get; set; }
    public T MinValue { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Type Type { get { return typeof(T); } }

}

public interface IParameterModel
{
    string Name { get; set; }
    Type Type { get; }
}

public class ParameterViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private ObservableCollection<IParameterModel> _parameters;
    public ObservableCollection<IParameterModel> Parameters
    {
        get { return _parameters; }
        set { Set(ref _parameters, value); }
    }
    public ParameterViewModel(IEnumerable<IParameterModel> parameters)
    {
        _parameters = new ObservableCollection<IParameter>(parameters);
    }
}

public class ParameterMockService
{
    public static List<IParameterModel> GetParameters()
    {
        var ret = new List<IParameterModel>();
        ret.Add(new ParameterModel<int> { Value = 50, Name = "Frequence" });
        ret.Add(new ParameterModel<int> { Value = 10, Name = "Word Count"});
        ret.Add(new ParameterModel<string> { Value = "EA2D", Name = "Command"});
        ret.Add(new ParameterModel<bool> { Value = false, Name = "Activate" });
        return ret;
    }
}
```

And the XAML

```
<Grid DataContext="{x:Type vm:ParameterViewModel}">
  <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Parameters}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
      <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Value">
          <!-- Here maybe a template selector -->
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
      </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
  </DataGrid> 
</Grid>
```

Maybe i have to make a ViewModel per different type in my parameter, but i don't really know the best way.
Thanks

Comment: What if you closed the generic ParameterModel<T> for every type you need and then create instances of those, would that work? For example:
class IntParameterModel : ParameterModel<int>

Or can you use dynamic instead? Just a thought.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use a DataTemplateSelector, here is one way of doing it.

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Value">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplateSelector>
        <local:ParameterDataTemplateSelector />
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplateSelector>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

In this DataTemplateSelector, we use the Type.Name with a prefix as the name of a DataTemplate defined in XAML somewhere.

```
public class ParameterDataTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        var pm = item as IParameterModel;
        var fe = container as FrameworkElement;
        if (pm != null && fe != null)
        {
            var dt = fe.TryFindResource("ParameterModel" + pm.Type.Name) as DataTemplate; // ParameterModelBoolean, ParameterModelString, ParameterModelInt32, etc...
            if (dt != null)
                return dt;
        }
        return base.SelectTemplate(item, container);
    }
}
```

The DataTemplates could be defined in several different locations. Below, I used Window.Resources but it could be in your app.xaml instead if they are to be used globally:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ParameterModelBoolean">
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock>
                <Run Text="Default Value: " />
                <Run Text="{Binding DefaultValue}" />
            </TextBlock>
            <TextBlock>
                <Run Text="Min Value: " />
                <Run Text="{Binding MinValue}" />
            </TextBlock>
            <TextBlock>
                <Run Text="Max Value: " />
                <Run Text="{Binding MaxValue}" />
            </TextBlock>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="Value:" />
                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Value}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ParameterModelString">
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock>
                <Run Text="Default Value: " />
                <Run Text="{Binding DefaultValue}" />
            </TextBlock>
            <TextBlock>
                <Run Text="Min Value: " />
                <Run Text="{Binding MinValue}" />
            </TextBlock>
            <TextBlock>
                <Run Text="Max Value: " />
                <Run Text="{Binding MaxValue}" />
            </TextBlock>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="String Value:" />
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Value}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ParameterModelInt32">
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock>
            <Run Text="Default Value: " />
            <Run Text="{Binding DefaultValue}" />
            </TextBlock>
            <TextBlock>
            <Run Text="Min Value: " />
            <Run Text="{Binding MinValue}" />
            </TextBlock>
            <TextBlock>
            <Run Text="Max Value: " />
            <Run Text="{Binding MaxValue}" />
            </TextBlock>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="Int32 Value:" />
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Value}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: I have a problem, my item in SelectTemplate is always null... I see my value, but with default template. Thanks for your help

Comment: It will be called with a null item a few times before it is called with a non-null item. Put a breakpoint on the first line in SelectTemplate and everytime it is hit, continue execution until you get a non-null item. You don't have enough code shown for me to debug it for you.

Comment: Nevermind, the item is null but the datatemplate is apply. Thanks